# Thymeleaf - having html tags inside js quotes

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf

I have this part of code in one of my thymeleaf views where I get some data through ajax:

```
success: function(data){
    data.forEach(function(item){
        $('#friends-list').append('<div onclick="selectUserToChat("' + item.id + '\,' + ' \'' +
            item.username + ')\'' + '); >' + item.username + '</div>');
    });
}
```

However when I try to run the application, I get an error saying Element type "div" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>". How do I deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `CDATA` block, so Thymeleaf doesn't try to interpret your javascript as html.

```
<script>
    // <![CDATA[

    // ...

    success: function (data) {
        data.forEach(function (item) {
            $('#friends-list').append('<div onclick="selectUserToChat("' + item.id + '\,' + ' \'' + item.username + ')\'' + '); >' + item.username + '</div>');
        });
    }

    // ...

    // ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes, and inside the string escape them using `\`:

```
.append("<div onclick=\"selectUserToChat(\"" + ...
```